# Pattern matching against decimal always fails with a nullable decimal accumulator

Tags: c#

What causes the `sum` to be always `null`?

```
object[] data = new object[]
{
    2.2M,
    3m,
    1,
    "string",
    true,
    false,
    2.3f
};

decimal? sum = null;
foreach (object x in data)
{
    if (x is decimal d)
        sum += d;
}
```

Comment: `decimal? sum = null;` why are you setting this to null then using `sum += d;` ?

Comment: you have to initiate the sum, set it to 0m

Comment: @Haitam: To know whether or not `data` has no decimal type.

Comment: But it doesn't make any sence, what is null + 2.2m ?

Comment: Try `sum = (sum ?? 0) + d;`

Comment: If you set `sum` to `null`, then `sum += 1` still is `null`.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity if you set sum to 0.0m, and after the foreach the sum is still 0.0m, you'll know that there was no decimal value in the data object.

Comment: @E.Hoxha, unless there was a decimal value of 0.0m of course ;)

Comment: @DavidArno true, a bad assumption on my part that it would be an unlikely scenario :P

Comment: "What causes the sum to be always null" - the fact that anything + `null` equals `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not good old *Linq* which has been specially designed for this?

```
  object[] data = new object[] {
    2.2M,
    3m,
    1,
   "string",
    true,
    false,
    2.3f };

  // If you want 2.2m + 3m == 5.2  
  var sum = data
    .OfType<decimal?>() // we want decimal only: 2.2M as well as 3m
    .Sum();             // summed up
```

**Edit**: if you want to obtain `null` (not `0m`) on empty filtred collection (i.e. when the collection *doesn't have* any `decimal` items) we have to modify the aggregation:

```
  var sum = data
    .OfType<decimal?>()
    .Aggregate((decimal?)null, 
               (s, a) => s == null ? a : s + a);
```

Comment: Doesn't that still return 0, even if the list of decimals empty? [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wBPF1v)

Comment: @john: Nice catch, thank you! If we want `null` as an outcome if the initial collection (`data`) doesn't have any `decimal` items we have to implement a custom aggregation.

Comment: And I got to learn something out of it - I've never used aggregate - so thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest option here is to use the null coalsecing operator `??`:

```
decimal? sum = null;
foreach (object x in data)
{
    if (x is decimal d)
        sum = (sum ?? 0) + d;
}
```

But you could also use LINQ:

```
var elements = data.OfType<decimal>();
decimal? sum = (elements.Any() ? (decimal?)elements.Sum() : null);
```

Comment: Side (and pure academic) note: The Linq is quite OK when `data` is an *array*, but can be a issue if `data` is, say, `File.ReadLines(...)`, since we have to read *twice*: `elements.Any()` and then `elements.Sum()`. Two readings can lead to data inconsistence (`Any` returns `true` when `Sum` sums up the file cleared) and overhead.